# In Laravel, how to send data from the view to the controller using paginate

Tags: laravel

I have a view to show fields that are completed by the user.

```
<tbody>                    
  @foreach($indicadores as $ind) 
    <tr>

      <td id="{{$ind->id}}">{{ $ind->nombre }}</td>

      <td>
       <select name="evaluacion[]"> 
           <option value="0">[Seleccione]</option>                               
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="1">1</option>                             
          </select>
      </td>

    </tr>
  @endfor    
</tbody>
```

In the view, I use the paginate() method to display the data. 
When I submit the data, I only receive data from the current page in the controller. 
How can I get the data from all the pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: every page is a new request, you cannot persist the previous page data, since web is stateless, so one way to overcome is using sessions.

Comment: thanks Sobin for answering. How can I know from which page of the pagete the request is made? I was reviewing the method $request-> fullUrl() but it doesn't pass the number of the page. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try to use this

Javascript function in View : window.location = "/" + selectedValue;

route.php : Route::get('/{selectedValue}', 'PageController@page');

Controller : public function page($selectedValue) { echo $selectedValue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{$indicadores->links()}}
```

Use this ater @endfor.
Also change `@endfor` to `@endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

After foreach loop you just echo the Laravel paginate method.

```
{{ $indicadores->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also appends get parameters to be persistent per pagination

```
{{ $indicadores->appends(request()->input())->render() }}
```